# Junit with lambdas and stream map

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I have the below method and Junit for that method for which i need to write Junit.

The Employee POJO class looks like

```
public class Employee {
    
    String id ;
    
    Department department; //another simple pojo class
```

The Junit fails with below NPE error s.getDepartment() evaluates to null.How can i avoid it

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.example.mockito.TodoService.lambda$0(TodoService.java:47)
>   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
> ```

```
void fetch(String date)

    {
          List<Employee> employeeList = todoRepository.call(date);
        
        employeeList=   employeeList
        .stream()
        .map(s -> { 
            
            System.out.println("in here map s.getDepartment() "  + s.getDepartment());//prints null in junit
            s.getDepartment().setDeptName("CSE");
        
        return s;
        } ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Below is the Junit

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TodoServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TodoService todoService;

    @Mock
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;



    private List<TodosObject> actualList;


    
    
    
    @Test
    public void  lambda() {
        String date = "2021";
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee e = new Employee();
        list.add(e);


        when(todoRepository.call(date)).thenReturn(list);

        todoService.fetch(date);
```

}

Comment: In the POJO you provided it doesn't look like you've created getters/setters. Do you create those anyhow and use them to set the values for an employee? Otherwise the NPE is logical.

Comment: I have created just ommited in example for brevity.Answer given by @Wouter van der Linde solves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to set the value of `Department` in the `lambda()` method.**

In `lambda()` you do:

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
Employee e = new Employee();
list.add(e);
```

Which doesn't set the value of Department. Then in `fetch()` you do `s.getDepartment().setDeptName("CSE");` which produces an NPE.

You either need to set the department in the `lambda()` method (e.g. `e.setDepartment(new Department())` or something equivalent) or check for null in the `fetch()` method, depending on your usecase. (e.g can `department` ever be null in production?)

Comment: Thanks adding `e.setDepartment(new Department( ))` worked can mock streams in my example ..suppose if it was calling some DAO method

Comment: Awesome, good to hear. :) You're right. It's a bad idea to try to mock the `Stream`.

Just to expand on the topic a bit more:
In general you want to setup POJO's in your test that are 'valid' and have known values so you can verify that your methods work on them as expected. (In this case that the name of the department is changed to 'CSE'.)

Comment: Ok thanks.I will mark your answer as correct